# Why does apache camel filter out HTTP headers

Tags: http-headers, apache-camel, cache-control, pragma

I was going through this link :
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Web_Services_and_Routing_with_Camel_CXF/files/Proxying-Headers.html

It states that when building bridge applications using HTTP or HTTP-based components, it is often necessary to remove or filter out certain headings or classes of headings in your route, in order to ensure that your application behaves as expected. Also in the org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpHeaderFilterStrategy it can be seen that lots of headers are being filtered out as follows :

```
protected void initialize() {
    getOutFilter().add("content-length");
    getOutFilter().add("content-type");
    getOutFilter().add("host");
    // Add the filter for the Generic Message header
    // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.5
    getOutFilter().add("cache-control");
    getOutFilter().add("connection");
    getOutFilter().add("date");
    getOutFilter().add("pragma");
    getOutFilter().add("trailer");
    getOutFilter().add("transfer-encoding");
    getOutFilter().add("upgrade");
    getOutFilter().add("via");
    getOutFilter().add("warning");

}
```

I know we can override this behavior by implementing our own filter strategy. But what is the reason for blocking the headers? For example, if I don't block the cache-control or pragma header, what side effects could it lead to?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the header filter you are referencing is a whitelist, not a blacklist. I.e. it will let through all the listed (http related) headers but drop all other headers that might have been added to your exchange while it was traveling through your routes. Normally you want those additional headers to be removed so they do not spill the beans about your system internals.

Comment: In the link provided above , it also stated that when a HTTP producer endpoint receives an exchange and converts it to the target message format, it handles the In message headers as follows:    **All other headers are converted to HTTP headers in the target message, with the exception of the following headers, which are blocked (based on a case-insensitive match):**

    _content-length
    content-type
    cache-control
    connection
    date
    pragma
    trailer
    transfer-encoding
    upgrade
    via
    warning_

Comment: this is not true, the HttpHeaderFilterStrategy will filter out all the general http headers. I am facing the same problem as it will filter the cache control header.